# Is it performance-effective to add CSS to a JavaScript file and dynamically load to HTML head tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If in a website, I add a JavaScript at the end of body and adds a large amount of CSS to that JavaScript, that dynamically gets added to the head of HTML page as the page is loaded and my JavaScript file is parsed, as the file resides at the end of the HTML page, after the whole page is loaded, does this slows down page?

As my CSS code is above 1000 lines (unminified) and I don't want external CSS (although it's cached) because of some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It does not slow down the page because the page has essentially completed loading all the HTML and other CSS by that point.

The browser builds the DOM model and the CSSOM as the HTML and CSS are being downloaded. By the time your script is reached, at the end, it's all mostly complete other than what you add at the end with javascript.

What I gather from re-reading your question is that you intend to load all your CSS via javascript that runs at the end of the page. The issue that may concern you is your added CSS will then start modifying the page. Potential problems can be making your page jump a bit, flash colors, change fonts, etc. depending on what your added CSS does.